Trimming multi-spline curve with Geometry Nodes

The start and end inputs of the Trim Curve node seem to impact all of the splines at once. Is it possible to treat the entire curve as one single unit with factor 0 referring to first position of the first spline and factor 1 referring to the last position of the last spline? So for instance, in the attached gif, increasing end value from 0 to 1 should uncover the text letter by letter from left to right, similar to the text writing effect.

Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but it’s a good question.

(Using Blender 4.2.3)

This answer was developed in two times. The original post is at the end. The front part is a generalization, including Markus von Broady approach.

Analysis
Trimming by Factor

Figure 1: The graduated axis is the Factor property accumulated over the set of splines. The colored top arrows are indicating the span of each spline along this scale, not their actual shape. It is to notice that by construction, the axis graduation is also the spline Index.
Let $N$ be the number of splines, and $\varepsilon \in [0,1]$ be the user-defined parameter controlling the trimming position $f$, with $f=\varepsilon N$. Portions of spline whose accumulated Factor is less than $f$ are displayed ; portions of spline whose accumulated Factor is greater than $f$ are hidden. $f$ can be written as $f = n+\alpha$, with $n \in [0,N-1]\cap \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$.
Let $i$ be a spline Index, and $E_i$ be defined as $E_i=f-i$. $E_i=(n-i)+\alpha$ is analyzed in the following cases:

$i \lt n$ (red case, spline fully displayed): $n-i \ge 1 \Rightarrow E_i \ge 1+\alpha \Rightarrow E_i \ge 1$.
$i = n$ (green case, spline partially displayed): $n-i = 0 \Rightarrow E_i = \alpha \Rightarrow E_i \in [0,1]$.
$i \gt n$ (blue case, spline fully hidden): $n-i \le -1 \Rightarrow E_i \le \alpha -1 \Rightarrow E_i \le 0$.

Consequently, $E_i=\varepsilon N - i$ is well suited to set the End input parameter of the Trim Curve node in Factor mode, its Start input parameter being set to $0$.
Trimming by Length

Figure 2: The graduated axis is the Length property (labeled $l_i$) accumulated over the set of splines. The colored top arrows are indicating the span of each spline along this scale, not their actual shape.
Let $L$ be the whole curve length, and $\varepsilon \in [0,1]$ be the user-defined parameter controlling the trimming position $l$, with $l=\varepsilon L$. Portions of spline whose accumulated Length is less than $l$ are displayed ; portions of spline whose accumulated Length is greater than $l$ are hidden. Let $n$ be the Index of the spline such that:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} l_j \le l \le \sum_{j=0}^{n} l_j = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} l_j + l_n
$$
Let $i$ be a spline Index, and $E_i$ be defined as $E_i=l-\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}l_j$. $E_i$ is analyzed in the following cases:

$i \lt n$ (red case, spline fully displayed): $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}l_j - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}l_j = \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}l_j \ge l_i \Rightarrow E_i \ge l_i$.
$i = n$ (green case, spline partially displayed): $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}l_j - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}l_j = 0 \Rightarrow E_i \in [0,l_i]$.
$i \gt n$ (blue case, spline fully hidden): $\sum_{j=0}^{n}l_j - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}l_j = -\sum_{j=n+1}^{i-1}l_j \le 0 \Rightarrow E_i \le 0$.

Consequently, $E_i=\varepsilon L - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}l_j$ is well suited to set the End input parameter of the Trim Curve node in Length mode, its Start input parameter being set to $0$.
NB: "Trimming by Factor" can be reinterpreted as "Trimming by Length" with $l_i=1$.
GeometryNodes modifiers

Figure 3: The 3D Viewport illustrates that the Factor rendering is lagging behind the Length rendering because the "e" inner loop is short compared with other splines.
"A326829 Factor" graph: Computation of $E_i=\varepsilon N - i$. $N$ is recovered by a Domain Size node set in Curve domain.
"A326829 Length" graph: Computation of $E_i=\varepsilon L - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}l_j$. $L$ is recovered by a Curve Length node, and $l_i$ by a Spline Length node. $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}l_j$ is returned by the Trailing socket of an Accumulate Field node set in Spline domain.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.3+)

Original proposal based on Selection socket

1. Let $N$ be the number of splines, recovered from a Domain Size node.  $\varepsilon$, the user-defined global End parameter, multiplied by $N$ is between $0$ and $N \varepsilon$. $N \varepsilon$ can be written as $N \varepsilon = n+\alpha$, with $n \in [0,N-1]\cap \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$.
2. The dark pinks nodes are completely trimming all the splines whose Index is greater than $n$.
3. The dark green nodes are trimming the spline of Index $n$ by the factor $\alpha$.
4. Splines of Index lower than $n$ are not modified.
(Blender 4.2.3+)

The only problem with this is that each spline gets the same factor regardless of the length, so splines with smaller length animate slowly.

Because you wrote "factor 0 " and "factor 1", and your Trim Curve node was set in Factor mode, I assumed the control parameter was Factor, not Length... May I suggest to reformulate the question stating Length instead of Factor, or even to post it as a new question ?

The original answer was reformulated and extended to include the trimming by length also.

You can accumulate spline lengths to offset the trim start (or end, if you also use the total curve length in the equation):

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Simple and elegant!


Here is another solution that takes into consideration the length of the spline. Not sure about the performance though.

